# Why aren't my check boxes binding in my bootstrap-ui angularjs modal popup?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've got a modal popup which contains a list of checkboxes. The list of controls is generated dynamically from a list and the ng-checked property is bound to the Selected property in my list model.

Generating the list of controls works perfectly if in a normal template but when I try to bind it in a modal popup the controls are created but the Selected property isn't bound correctly.

You can see in this plunkr that the model has the Selected property set and when you use the checkbox the Selected property changes.

I've tried cloaning my objects in the resolve functions in the parent controller. I suspect this is to do with the modal window creating 2 scopes but I thought that using an object reference as a container for my model array should get around that.

Here's the code which launches my modal window.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modaltemplate.html',
    backdrop: 'static',
    controller: 'RoleModalController',
    resolve: {
      privileges: function() {
        return $scope.privileges;
      },
      role: function() {
        return null;
      }
    }
  });
```

Here's the controller for the modal.

```
.controller('RoleModalController', 
["$scope", "$modalInstance", "privileges", "role",
function($scope, $modalInstance, privileges, role) {
  $scope.form = {};

  $scope.privileges = privileges;

  $scope.role = {
    Name: null,
    Description: null
  };

  $scope.ok = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('ok');
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };

  var init = function() {
    if (!_.isNull(role)) {
      $scope.role = role;

      // for each privilege in the role, set Selected = true in the 
      // corresponding privilege in the in the privileges collection
      _.each(role.Privileges, function(priv) {
        var foundPriv = _.find($scope.privileges.all, function(p) {
          return p.PrivilegeId === priv.PrivilegeId;
        });
        _.extend(foundPriv, {
          Selected: true
        });
      });
    }
  }

  init();
}
```

Here's a plunk of http://plnkr.co/edit/fvbHlF?p=preview

Edit: I've just updated my plunk to show this "working" outside the modal and it doesn't so perhaps this isn't an issue with the additional scopes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is the way you are using the [`ng-checked`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) directive. Note that only if the expression defined on the `ng-checked` evaluates to true, the special attribute "checked" will be set on the element. In your case the `roleSelectionChanged()` is not evaluating to true (you probably wanted to use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)).

Remove the `ng-checked` directive from the template and it should work.

Comment: I've been looking at this for for 2 days. You are 100% correct and I also worked this out about 20 seconds after I posted my edit to the question. It's incredible what reading your code can achieve rather than just assuming what it does. Thanks for taking the time to answer.